# What is the best independent test suite for benchmarking JavaScript engines?

Tags: javascript, benchmarking, interpreter, v8, spidermonkey

I'm looking for the best tool for benchmarking the speed of JavaScript interpreters.

Preferably this shouldn't be a tool written by a conflicted party such as Mozilla or Google, although I understand that these might give the most accurate representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [Dromaeo](http://dromaeo.com/). It was made by John Resig, creator of jQuery. Though it has a Mozilla Wiki page, that page states that Resig is creating it in a way that will satisfy all browser vendors by providing accurate information.

Comment: Finally, an answer! Thanks David, that looks like an excellent solution.

Comment: You're welcome. I would definitely give the Mozilla Wiki page a read, though; Dromaeo does have some limitations. It's still a good JS test suite.